# Как создать базу данных postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, python, база-данных, postgresql

Есть приложение (блог), как создать базу данных postgreSQL. Код полностью рабочий, исходники на гитхабе. Всё вроде как понятно, кроме одного - Как создать эту самую db ? Само приложение запускается на локальном сервере с помощью virtualenv

Хоть в readme есть и "text hint", но я не понимаю, куда вставлять этот самый text hint ?

Сами исходники : https://github.com/dlamichhane/Flask-blog/tree/master/flaskblog

Comment: Какую операционную систему используете?

Comment: @FeroxTL Ubuntu 14.04. С базами данных мало имел общего, лишь с MySQL в php, там всё до боли просто, но про PostgreSQL ничего не знаю, а про её использование так вообще не слышал даже

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В Postgresql есть приложение psql. Но тут стоит учесть, что вход в базу осуществляется (по умолчанию) с тем же пользователем, что и тот, под которым вы зарегистрированы в системе. Postgresql создаёт при установке пользователя postgres (системного). Именно под его учётной записью необходимо выполнять все действия. Итак, сначала становимся пользователем postgres

```
sudo su postgres
```

и запускаем под ним `psql`. Далее выведется приглашение командной строки postgres. Стоит упомянуть, что в Postgresql пользователь postgres - это что-то вроде суперпользователя, т.е. он имеет доступ ко всем базам и по умолчанию все базы создаются от него. Также есть небольшой набор команд для администрирования, например, `\l` - вывести список доступных баз данных. Чтобы создать базу данных необходимо написать стандартную команду SQL -

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
```

, например. Чтобы создать пользователя воспользуйтесь командой

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH password 'qwerty';
```

Но на данную базу данных у пользователя не будет прав. Чтобы создать базу с владельцем добавьте опциональный параметр `OWNER`

```
CREATE DATABASE test_database OWNER test_user;
```

Можно также дать права на базу пользователю командой

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON DATABASE test_db TO test_user;
```

Для удаления базы данных можно воспользоваться командой

```
DROP DATABASE test_db;
```

В принципе этого достаточно, чтобы начать знакомство с Postgresql.

Comment: И, получается, чтобы создать базу данных (по этому тутору https://github.com/dlamichhane/Flask-blog/tree/master/flaskblog), нужно просто ввести команды оттуда в консоль под юзером postgres ?

Comment: @vagabund Да, я думаю это сработает. Но в Postgresql есть ещё и права на таблицы, которые нужно дополнительно разграничить, поэтому я советую для начала попросту всё делать из-под того пользователя, под которым вы непосредственно пишете/читаете из бд. В случае в flask и sqlalchemy есть встроенная команда, которая создаст вам всю базу данных из моделей - [create_all](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая утилита как pgadmin.
Она позволяет управлять базами данных в графическом режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Подключиться к системной базе данных postgres затем создать новую базу данных.

```
con = connect(
    dbname='postgres' user='user', 
    host = 'localhost', password='password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE database')
```

За дальнейшими подробностями [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426770/4249707)